# Bug in type conversions! Both in MSVC and GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

The bug occurs when changing from ( unsigned long long ) to ( double ). Тhe error is very small and happens only in some numbers, but it is there. The error is the same in MSVC and GCC.

Check yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
             long long a = 834146832894220100LL;
    unsigned long long b = 834146832894220100ULL;

    printf( "%.16f\n%.16f\n",
        (( double )a / 1e+18),
        (( double )b / 1e+18)
    );

    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
0.8341468328942201
0.8341468328942202
```

This is asm code from MSVC:

```
// long long a = 834146832894220100LL;
    mov         dword ptr [a],12D5744h
    mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],0B937C20h
// unsigned long long b = 834146832894220100ULL;
    mov         dword ptr [b],12D5744h
    mov         dword ptr [ebp-30h],0B937C20h
// This is unsigned to double conversion:
    mov         eax,dword ptr [b] 
    mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-30h] 
    mov         dword ptr [ebp-100h],eax 
    mov         dword ptr [ebp-0FCh],ecx 
    mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0FCh] 
    mov         dword ptr [ebp-104h],edx 
    and         dword ptr [ebp-0FCh],7FFFFFFFh 
    fild        qword ptr [ebp-100h] 
    and         dword ptr [ebp-104h],80000000h 
    mov         dword ptr [ebp-108h],0 
    fild        qword ptr [ebp-108h] 
    fchs             
    faddp       st(1),st 
    fdiv        qword ptr [__real@43abc16d674ec800 (0C07870h)]
    mov         esi,esp 
    sub         esp,8 
    fstp        qword ptr [esp] 
// This is signed to double conversion:
    fild        qword ptr [a] 
    fdiv        qword ptr [__real@43abc16d674ec800 (0C07870h)] 
    sub         esp,8 
    fstp        qword ptr [esp]
```

What is your opinion ?

Comment: Besides that this site is about facts, not opinions, check out `std:numeric_limits<double>::digits10` for your platform.

Comment: why do you assume that it's a bug in the compiler? :)

Comment: @jalf likely because `clang` does *not* exhibit the same behavior (at least not on my Mac x64), where the outputs are the same. I assume the OP left clang out of that list for a reason (or perhaps he never tried it?).

Comment: Can't reproduce in either [g++ 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8f595cc215c1366) or MSVC12.

Comment: digits10 returns 15. Ok, the difference is in the 16 number.
MSCV: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008
GCC : gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Comment: But anyway. Do not understand why is this difference. There is only one arithmetic operation: division with same divisor.

Comment: It'd be more useful to show the different assembly code contributing to the different calculations, e.g. `g++ -S` if you really want an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disassembled the code produced in gcc 4.9.1 on i386. it produced the same exact code for each. I'd guess that your compiler is doing constant evaluation differently internally depending on the type. You could try different optimization levels and/or change the order of signed vs unsigned around.
It could also be a bug in the printf code that has to do with setting rounding modes differently for the first/rest of the conversions to text.

Comment: No, it is not printf(). a = 0x3feab154b2eaf702, b = 3feab154b2eaf703.

Comment: can you post the dissassembled code or post the executable?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I can't vote up your answer, because my reputation went down a lot from this post :)